# jQuery selector using multiple data-* attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use an attribute-selector, created dynamically from a variable, but it only react to the beginning of string in the variable (the non-dynamic portion):

```
var dataKeys = 'td[data-key="name"],td[data-key="code"],td[data-key="date"]';
dataKeys = dataKeys + ',td[data-key="' + fieldsArray[i] + '"]';
```

And when I use it as follows:

```
$(dataKeys, this).each(function ()
```

It only reacts to attribute-values of `"name"`, `"code"` and `"date"` keys, when dataKeys:

```
td[data-key="serial_no"], td[data-key="name"], td[data-key="code"], td[data-key="date"], td[data-key="serial_no"]"
```

Comment: Do you have `td[data-key="' + fieldsArray[i] + '"]'` inside of `this`? Do `console.log($(dataKeys, this));` to see selector

Comment: And what's held in the `fieldsArray[i]` variable? Have you logged that to console to check it's what you think it is?

Comment: Are you sure the `fieldsArray[i]` contain `serial_no`?

Comment: $(dataKeys, this) selector does not have serial_no
,the selector is "td[data-key="name"],td[data-key="code"],td[data-key="date"]"

Comment: Zakaria Acharki fieldsArray[i] contains string 'serial_no'

Comment: I suspect you have a syntax error or your markup is not correct.  This example does exactly what you're looking for and works fine... https://jsfiddle.net/dygb7noq/

Comment: Further to Archer's comment, and my own suspicions, I'd suggest pasting your code into [JS Hint](http://jshint.com/), or any other online JavaScript linting tool, to see what, if any, syntax errors there might be. Incidentally, have you checked the browser's JavaScript console to see if there are any reported errors there?

Answer (score -2):

I got your code parts to work inside 1 snippet. I only had 1 problem at first: my browser stripped the `TD` elements because they where not inside a proper html table table, and so the selector did not find the `td`s

So i put it inside a table and it worked. (see snippet below).

Most probably the error is somewhere else in your code. maybe its good to add some logging or debug and see which values your variables have. I only  give you 1 possible solution.

```js
var fieldsArray = ['dynamic', 'serial_no'];
var dataKeys = 'td[data-key="name"],td[data-key="code"],td[data-key="date"]';
dataKeys = dataKeys + ',td[data-key="' + fieldsArray[1] + '"]';

console.log('selector', dataKeys);
$(dataKeys).each(function() {
  console.log('i am', this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-key="name">hey</td>
    <td data-key="code">hi</td>
    <td data-key="excluded">hoho</td>
    <td data-key="serial_no">hoho</td>
    <tr>
      <table>
```

Comment: I rolled back your change to the question as it VASTLY modified it from what the OP was asking, and was basically you posting this suggested answer as the question itself.  Please do not do this again.  If you have an issue then flag it for moderation.

Comment: @Archer i turned his code parts into 1 workable snippet (the original code parts where unusable to create an answer upon). The snippet did NOT work as for the answer i posted. probably though the error is somewhere else in his code.

Comment: You VASTLY modified the question.  That is not how you make suggestions to the OP.   Flag for moderation if you disagree.